# How to use object property as HTTP GET request parameter in Angular app?

Tags: angular, typescript

I have `Job` & `Manager` objects in a JSON file.
They are connected by `managerId` like so:

```
export interface IJob {
  id: number;
  title: string;
  description: string;
  employeeId?: number;
  managerId: string;
  imageUrl: string;
}


export interface IManager {
  id: number;
  fullName: string;
  email: string;
  phone?: number;
  password: string;
  contactPreference: string;
}
```

I am able to display the job title & manager ID's of ***all jobs*** using the below table rows:

```
<tr *ngFor="let job of jobs">
    <td>{{ job.title }}</td>
    <td>{{job.managerId}}</td>
</tr>
```

Here is the Typescript:

```
getAllJobs(): void {
    this.jobService.getJobs().subscribe(
        jobs => {
            this.jobs = jobs;
        },
        error => this.errorMessage = <any>error
     );
}
```

Now, instead of displaying the `job.managerId`, I wan to use this value to read manager.fullName from my `Manager` object.

Below is my attempt at this.

HTML:

```
<td>{{getManagerId(offer.managerId)}}</td>
```

Typescript:

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.managerService.getManagers().subscribe(
    managers => {
      this.allManagers = managers;
    },
    error => this.errorMessage = <any>error
  );

  this.jobService.getJobs().subscribe(
    jobs => {
      this.jobs = jobs;
  },
  error => this.errorMessage = <any>error
  );
}

getManagerId(mId) {
    return this.allManagers.filter(function (obj) {
        return obj.id === mId;
    })[0].fullName;
}
```

This code displays the `manager.fullName` if there is only one record being read.
However, I get this error message:

> Cannot read property 'fullName' of undefined

And if there are multiple records read, then nothing is displayed & the above error message is logged multiple times.

Can someone please tell me how I can make this `getManagerId()` method to deal with multiple records, & how to get rid of this error message?

Stackblitz at: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cy42jm

Comment: what is the result of `console.log(this.jobs)?`

Comment: Hi @PrashantPimpale, I've logged it to the question above

Comment: There are possibly two ways to do that: 1) First load manager by its id when you load this Job list (i.e one by one) 2) Load all Manager list and filter it by manager Id

Comment: Can you provide stackBlitz where I can try?

Comment: OK, I will try to create stackBlitz for it. In meantime, I will post a `getAllManagers` method that I have in my `Manager Service`

Comment: @PrashantPimpale Do I share the editor URL or the app URL? Sorry, first time! :)

Comment: Share Editor...

Comment: Check this demo:https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vddx5g is it fine?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195987/discussion-between-prashant-pimpale-and-user9847788).

Answer (score 0):

```
filteredJobs = [
 {
  'employeeId ':'73','
   employeename':'bar4'
 },
 {
  'employeeId':'45',
  'employeename':'bara'
 },
 ...
]
```

If you want to get an array of matching elements, use the `filter()` method instead:

```
this.filteredJobs.filter(x => x.employeeId === '45');
```

This will return an array of objects. If you want to get an array of employeename properties, you can do this with the `map()` method:

```
this.filteredJobs.filter(x => x.employeeId === '45').map(x => x.employeename);
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming

```
filteredJobs = [
 {
   employeeId: 1,
   employee: undefined,
   title: 'Manager'
 },
 {
   employeeId: 2,
   employee: undefined,
   title: 'Manager'
 }
]
```

After your call to `this.filteredJobs = this.performFilter(this.listFilter);`

```
this.filteredJobs.forEach(job => 
   this.employeeService.getEmployee(job.employeeId)
        .subscribe(employee => {
            job.employee = employee; 
         })
   );
```

In the .html

```
<tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let job of filteredJobs">
        <td>{{ job.title }}</td>
        <td *ngIf="job.employee">{{ job.employee.name }} </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

This is not the most efficient way, since your server is going to get a lot of requests.

A better way to approach this if you have access to the "server" code, would be to return the employee when you request the jobs, otherwise it might be good to take a look at building your own [Async Pipe](https://blog.angularindepth.com/angular-question-rxjs-subscribe-vs-async-pipe-in-component-templates-c956c8c0c794)